# Formatting Date String abbreviating month

Tags: c#, format

I would like to format a standard .NET `DateTime` string as follows

2014-01-01 => Jan 2014

I can get the date form "January 2014" by using `ToString("y")` but how can I abbreviate the month?

Is this even possible?

C#
Visual Studio 2012
.NET 4.5

Comment: You want to format your `DateTime` as `2014-01-01 => Jan 2014` or just `Jan 2014`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `MMM` format as in:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd => MMM yyyy")
```

Which produces:

```
2014-08-06 => Aug 2014
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "MMM", take a look at this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I dont speak german but fortunately I know that page well in the english version. I am accepting @Sina Iravians answer as he gives actual code but thanks for the answer