# Get Dates lists between 2 dates C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

how i can get dates ranges list between 2 dates

for example,

> `start date` is 12 February
>    
>   `end date` is 23 May

so, the result must be like

`12-Feb to 28-Feb 
1-Mar to 31-Mar 
1-April to 30-April
1-May to 23-May`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I loop through a date range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847580/how-do-i-loop-through-a-date-range)

Comment: why does February become Feb but April stays April?

Comment: Do you need to loop over these ranges or do you just need a list with the dates required?

Comment: Basically you create DateTime for first day and add one day till reaching last day. Use  AddDays. Google for a snipet.

Comment: loop over ranges

Comment: It's not clear what your comment of "loop over ranges" is meant to indicate, but it sounds like you probably just want to consider three parts to the result: 1) the month that includes the start; 2) the months entirely between the start and end; 3) the month that includes the end. You may want to handle "start and end are in the same month" as a special case for simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose you are checking only one year, i.e. the current one (2018).
Of course you can make `StartDate` and `EndDate` parametric.

There's nothing special in the code below; I used `"d-MMMM"` as date format since you seemed to ask for the minimum number of days (`"d"` does that, i.e. selects `1` and not `01` for the first day of a month) and the "long" name of the month ("MMMM" does that, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31939215/5480409)).
If instead you just want the abbreviation, i.e. "Feb" for "February", you can use "MMM" (check [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25162903/5480409)).

```
DateTime StartDate = new DateTime(2018, 2, 12);
DateTime EndDate = new DateTime(2018, 5, 23);

for (int i = 0; i <= EndDate.Month - StartDate.Month; i++)
{
    DateTime FirstDay = new DateTime(2018, StartDate.Month + i, 1);
    if (i == 0)
    {
        FirstDay = StartDate;
    }
    DateTime LastDay = new DateTime(2018, StartDate.Month + i, DateTime.DaysInMonth(2018, FirstDay.Month));
    if (i == EndDate.Month - StartDate.Month)
    {
        LastDay = EndDate;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(FirstDay.ToString("d-MMMM") + " to " + LastDay.ToString("d-MMMM"));
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

You can also use the following code to make it "cross-year":

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    PrintDateList(new DateTime(2018, 2, 12), new DateTime(2018, 5, 23));
    PrintDateList(new DateTime(2018, 11, 12), new DateTime(2019, 2, 23));

    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void PrintDateList(DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate)
{
    Console.WriteLine("");
    int TotalMonths = EndDate.Month - StartDate.Month +
                     (EndDate.Year - StartDate.Year) * 12;

    int CurrentYear = StartDate.Year;
    int MonthsToSubtract = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= TotalMonths; i++)
    {
        int CurrentMonth = StartDate.Month + i;

        if (StartDate.Month + i > 12)
        {
            if ((StartDate.Month + i) % 12 == 1)
            {
                CurrentYear++;
                Console.WriteLine(CurrentYear.ToString());
                MonthsToSubtract = StartDate.Month + i - 1;
            }

            CurrentMonth = StartDate.Month + i - MonthsToSubtract;
        }

        DateTime FirstDay = new DateTime(CurrentYear, CurrentMonth, 1);
        if (i == 0)
        {
            FirstDay = StartDate;
        }
        DateTime LastDay = new DateTime(CurrentYear, CurrentMonth, DateTime.DaysInMonth(CurrentYear, FirstDay.Month));
        if (i == TotalMonths)
        {
            LastDay = EndDate;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(FirstDay.ToString("d-MMMM") + " to " + LastDay.ToString("d-MMMM"));
    }
}
```

The output is

> 12-February to 28-February
>   1-March to 31-March
>   1-April to 30-April
>   1-May to 23-May
>
> 12-November to 30-November
>   1-December to 31-December
>   1-January to 31-January
>   1-February to 23-February

Since you asked, I replaced `Console.WriteLine` with a `List`:

```
private static void PrintDateList(DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate)
{
        List<Tuple<DateTime>> EventsDatesRangeList = new List<Tuple<DateTime>>();
        Console.WriteLine("");
        int TotalMonths = EndDate.Month - StartDate.Month +
                        (EndDate.Year - StartDate.Year) * 12;

        int CurrentYear = StartDate.Year;
        int MonthsToSubtract = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= TotalMonths; i++)
        {
            int CurrentMonth = StartDate.Month + i;

            if (StartDate.Month + i > 12)
            {
                if ((StartDate.Month + i) % 12 == 1)
                {
                    CurrentYear++;
                    Console.WriteLine(CurrentYear.ToString());
                    MonthsToSubtract = StartDate.Month + i - 1;
                }

                CurrentMonth = StartDate.Month + i - MonthsToSubtract;
            }

            DateTime FirstDay = new DateTime(CurrentYear, CurrentMonth, 1);
            if (i == 0)
            {
                FirstDay = StartDate;
            }
            DateTime LastDay = new DateTime(CurrentYear, CurrentMonth, DateTime.DaysInMonth(CurrentYear, FirstDay.Month));
            if (i == TotalMonths)
            {
                LastDay = EndDate;
            }
                Console.WriteLine(FirstDay.ToString("d-MMMM") + " to " + LastDay.ToString("d-MMMM"));
            EventsDatesRangeList.Add(new Tuple<DateTime>(FirstDay));
            EventsDatesRangeList.Add(new Tuple<DateTime>(LastDay));

        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: very nice could you try this dates (new DateTime(2018, 2, 12), new DateTime(2019, 11, 12)

Comment: I guess you are asking because it gave 29 days for February 2019, right? I edited my code and tested it for both 2019 and 2020 (a leap year).

Comment: see insted i print the result i store it in created list

Comment: EventsDatesRangeList.Add(new Tuple<DateTime>(FirstDay));
                    EventsDatesRangeList.Add(new Tuple<DateTime>(LastDay));

Comment: replace the code then check the result the code will change the year to 2020 in the final

Comment: what's the type of `EventsDatesRangeList`?

Comment: if the type is `List<Tuple<DateTime>>`, I replaced it in my code and edited the post. I dont't get the year change.

Comment: try (new DateTime(2018, 11, 12), new DateTime(2019, 2, 23)) then sort the list you will see its jumped to 1/2/2020

Comment: the result will be 12/11/2018,30/11/2018,01/12/2018,31/12/2018,01/01/2019,31/01/2019,23/02/2019,1/02/2020

Comment: I tried the dates you gave me but I don't get that result, I posted what I get, check my answer for the picture. I copied and pasted the code in my answer, did you?

Comment: dear could you try 17/01/2016 -- 30/04/2018 cross 3 years

Comment: still skipped 01-12-2017 -- 31-12-2017

Comment: Meaning...? What happened?

Comment: jumped from 01-11-2017 -- 30/11/2017  to 01/01/2018 --31/01/2018 which is  skipped 01-12-2017 31-12-2017